Extended events to track autoupdate statistics for Azure SQL Database
I would like to monitor what stats are being updated and when. It seems that the auto_stats extended event is exactly what I am looking for, but it looks like it's only available for regular SQL Server and not Azure SQL Database (which is what I am using). Is there any equivalent for Azure SQL Database, or am I out of luck?
Thanks for any help!
